# Число - сокращается?

Tags: сочетаемость

Нормально ли сказано "их число сокращается"?
Может ли **число** уменьшаться, расти, изменяться?
Вроде бы формальных запретов нет, но как-то странно звучит.

Или изменяться может только численность?

*Я написал подобное машинально, отвечая на другой вопрос - и тут же поймал себя на сомнении.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Число в значении "количество" может сокращаться. Зафиксировано в словаре сочетаемости Института Русского языка 2002г.

Comment: Спасибо. Значит, на пустом месте засомневался.